# how to create the last Button of 13 in a gridlayout to stretch

Tags: java

i am having trouble with designing my button, ive created 13 and made it 5,3 but the last button does not stretch to the width of the 3 columns.

it is meant to look like this
[example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKkR7.jpg)

here is my code, if anyone can offer any suggestions thatd be helpful, thank you.

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Frame extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[]args){

        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("MyFrame");
        Panel myPanel = new Panel();
        myFrame.add(myPanel);
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.setSize(300,400);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Panel extends JPanel
{
    JButton zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,clear, negative,convert;
    JRadioButton k2p,p2k;
    JTextArea area;
    ButtonGroup conversion;
    public Panel() {

        zero = new JButton("0");
        one = new JButton("1");
        two = new JButton("2");
        three = new JButton("3");
        four = new JButton("4");
        five = new JButton("5");
        six = new JButton("6");
        seven = new JButton("7");
        eight = new JButton("8");
        nine = new JButton("9");
        clear = new JButton("C");
        negative = new JButton("-");
        convert = new JButton("Convert");
        area = new JTextArea();

        conversion = new ButtonGroup();
        conversion.add(k2p= new JRadioButton("Kilograms to Pounds"));
        conversion.add(p2k= new JRadioButton("Pounds to Kilograms"));

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel westPanel = new JPanel();


        westPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,3));

        westPanel.add(zero);
        westPanel.add(one);
        westPanel.add(two);
        westPanel.add(three);
        westPanel.add(four);
        westPanel.add(five);
        westPanel.add(six);
        westPanel.add(seven);
        westPanel.add(eight);
        westPanel.add(nine);
        westPanel.add(negative);
        westPanel.add(clear);
        westPanel.add(convert);



        add(westPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

}
```

Comment: `GridLayout` must size all of its components equally. You will have to use another layout manager such as `GridBagLayout`, `GroupLayout` or composite layouts (one within the other).

Comment: Also, you are better off creating an array of buttons instead of each one individually.

Answer (score 2):

[`GridLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) divides its space equally amongst all of its compoenents:

> The GridLayout class is a layout manager that lays out a container's components in a rectangular grid. The container is divided into **equal-sized rectangles**, and one component is placed in each rectangle.

(emphasis mine) Your alternatives are other layout managers, like `GridBagLayout`, `GroupLayout` or using a composite layout, which means nesting layout managers one inside the other.

Here I'll be using composite layouts by nesting the `GridLayout` inside a `BorderLayout` in the `CENTER` position and the `convert` button is in the `PAGE_END` position:

[image]

```
class Panel extends JPanel {

    JButton[] numberButtons = new JButton[10];
    JButton nine, clear, negative, convert;

    public Panel() {

        for (int i = 0; i < numberButtons.length; i++)
            numberButtons[i] = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
        clear = new JButton("C");
        negative = new JButton("-");
        convert = new JButton("Convert");

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel westPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 3));
        for (int i = 0; i < numberButtons.length; i++)
            buttonsPanel.add(numberButtons[i]);
        buttonsPanel.add(negative);
        buttonsPanel.add(clear);

        westPanel.add(buttonsPanel);
        westPanel.add(convert, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        add(westPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

I also created a `JButton[]` for the numbered buttons, it's usually a better choice. You can add the other buttons there too, but I think it will only be detrimental.